# node GET request won't show up on html page, only loads - doesnt return error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, postgresql, http

When I send a route.get request from the serve it responds with JSON data successfully and displays on localhost:/view/product page, however, I want it to process my client side html page and display the database info into the table there. It is not doing that.

My goal is to GET this data and display it into a simple html table on the localhost:3000/view/product route.

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

My html table attempt:

```
<html> 

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css">
  <div>
     <header> 
      <h2><a href="/"><i></i> VIEW PRODUCTS  </a></h2>
     </header>
  </div>
</head>

<body>
<div id="table">
  <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="productTable" border=1>
      <thead>
          <th> Product Name </th>
          <th> Quantity </th> 
          <th> Price </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="productTable"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$.get('/view/product', {}, function(results) {
  let res = '';
  results.forEach(data => {
    res += `<tr><td>${data.productname}</td><td>${data.quantity}</td><td>${data.price}</td></tr>`
  })
  $('#place-here').html(res)
});

</script>
```

my get request:

```
 route.get("/view/product", async function (req, res) {
      try {
        const results = await db.query("SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY createdAt DESC;",
       );

        // console.log(results);
        // res.status(200).json({
        //   status: "success",
        //   results: results.rows.length,
        //   data: {
        //     orders: results.rows,
        //   },
        // });
      } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
      }
    });
```

loading the html page in my index.js file:

```
app.get('/view/product',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('view.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Comment: Why do you show two separate GET handlers for `/view/product` on your server?

Comment: Also, your  HTML page shows no `#place-here` element for the client-side Javascript to operate on.

Comment: Ok thats a good question.... I thought I needed one to render the actual html file and the other to grab data from the postgres db. I added <tbody id="productTable"></tbody> but it still only displays the json data and not the html page @jfriend00 –

Comment: You should not have two route handlers for the same route path that are both GETs.  Your Ajax route (and the corresponding handler on the server) should be using a different path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same path for both your page load and for the Ajax call to fetch JSON as they are both GET routes so only the first one registered with your Express server will ever get a chance to see the incoming request.

I'd suggest you change the Ajax call to something like `/api/products` and then change the corresponding definition on your server for the route that returns JSON.